# java regex search and replace all?

Tags: java, regex

I have an example input that can be of any length and want to add a space every 4 characters.

for example input = xxxxxxxxxxxx

result I expect: xxxx xxxx xxxx

I have looked at the `replaceAll()` method but wondering how I can create a match that returns me the 4th, 8th, 12th etc character index so I can do something like this:

```
input.replaceAll("([\\S\\s)]{4})\\G", " " + input.charAt(index - 1))
```

where index somehow gets modified to get the appropriate index in which the regular expression of mine has found the 4th character.

Comment: Do you want a regex solution? It can be done easier without

Comment: How can it be done easier? I must note down that the input string is dynamic and can change. So while its being changed, i want to auto format it

Comment: I was thinking of Rahul Tripathi's answer, where you just parse the string and add a space every 4th character

Answer (score 4):

```
"xxxxxxxxxxxx".replaceAll(".{4}(?!$)","$0 ");
```

This won't add trailing space to the last segment.

Comment: `....` is the same length, and easier to read, than `.{4}`, but +1 anyway, especially the "not at the end" whistle

Comment: @Bohemian  thx. you are right for the `....`, but if `n>5`,  I would say `.{n}` would be easier to read.  :)

Comment: It works if the format is already xxxxxxxxx

But what if the format is only partially done ie xxxx xxxxxxxxxx?

I tried that approach and what happens is that it increases the space from the first group of characters leading to something like this instead:

xxxx  xxxxxxxx with double space

Comment: @jonney `want to add a space every 4 characters` you didn't say anything about the "partially done" case. if you want to add space for every 4 non-empty chars, you can try `\\S{4}(?!=\\s)` I didn't test though.

Comment: @Kent any suggestions? tried the above you mentioned and still added extra space

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `replaceAll(".{1,4}+(?!$)", "$0 ")`

- `.{1,4}+` will match any 1-4 characters (+ will make it possessive)
- `(?!$)` which are not right before end of string
- `$0 "` will replace it with content from group 0 (which is current match) plus space

---

Actually I overcomplicated this regex. You can find simpler version based on same idea in [@Kent's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29969938/1393766).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this wihout using regex:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
int i = str.length() - 4;

while (i > 0)
{
    str.insert(i, " ");
    i = i - 4;
}

System.out.println(str.toString());
```

With regex:

```
String myString = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
String str = myString.replaceAll("(.{4})(?!$)", "$0 ");
return str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping; $1 (and upwards) will get replaced with `matcher.getGroup(1)` .

Answer (score 0):

This will not add a space if there is one

```
String s = "xxxxxxxx xxxxx x xx x";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\w{4}(?!\\s)", "$0 " ));
```

Outmput: `xxxx xxxx xxxx x x xx x`

[demo](http://ideone.com/LWoDOq)